# Struct within struct C#

Tags: c#

While studying C# , I came across the following piece of code:

```
public struct position
{
    public static readonly position Zero;
    public double x;
    public double y;
    ...
}
```

It's not the whole code, but this is the part I need help understanding. Wouldn't creating a instance of the struct inside the struct create a infinite loop?

Comment: well have you tried it yourself?

Comment: The key here is `static`. Leave that out and yes, it would be a problem, and the compiler would complain. But a `static` is, storage-wise, part of the class, not the instance.

Comment: Consider `int.MaxValue` or `DateTime.Now`. They're both members of structs and they both have the same type as the struct. But neither of them will cause a cycle because one is a constant and the other is a static member and they're both accessed via the type name itself, not via an instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Wouldn't creating a instance of the struct inside the struct create a infinite loop?

Indeed, and if you remove the `static` keyword, you actually get the following error message:

> Struct member 'position.Zero' of type 'position' causes a cycle in the struct layout

So, why does `static` "fix" the problem? Because [static members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members#static-members) are not stored per instance of the struct. Instead, static members are something akin to a "global variable" in C#.

Thus, in your example,

- a position is defined by its `x`, `y`, etc. values. These are the values that "take up space" when you declare a new instance of your struct.
- In addition, there is a special "constant" `postition.zero`, containing a position with all its values set to the default value. (I put "constant" in quotes, since it's technically not a C# constant, but it behaves similarly to one, since it's `readonly`.)

Comment: "Syntactic sugar" is a fairly specific term, and so is "global variable". A `static` member is "somewhat like" a global variable in other languages, but there is no syntactic sugar involved -- there is no different or more elaborate way to write `static` declarations.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: You are right, it's not "syntactic sugar". I have rephrased it.